# Ошибка при переходе между страницами и передаче информации между ними

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

У меня есть объект, и я хочу передать его между страницами.

Проблема в том, что в старом проекте оно работает, но после обновления и добавления в новый проект появилась ошибка
передачи между первой и второй страницей.

```cs
public async Task GotoPage2()
{
    if (mainCar.TypeCar != null)
        await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new Car_add_company(mainCar));
}
```

передача между второй и третьей страницей

```cs
public async Task GotoPage2()
{
    if (mainCar.MarkCar != null)
        await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new Car_add_model(mainCar));
}
```

Сама ошибка:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
Android.Content.Res.Resources+NotFoundException: 'Resource ID #0x0'
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: одну секунду,сейчас скопирую ошибку

Comment: я скопировала ошибку